# Acrobat Javascript Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to have javascript regular expression to catch the text from .pdf file. 
e.g. want to catch this text: `20-40-55 FIG 20`

I wrote the following expression for that:

```
/[\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} FIG \d+]/g
```

It is not catching the required text.

If I pass there any other text of .pdf file, it is showing it in found items.

Comment: Remove the square brackets.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the square brackets:

```
/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} FIG \d+/g
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZ5wA4/2)

Square brackets created a character class and the regex matched just 1 character from that set. See [*Character Classes or Character Sets*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: I did this also..
but it is not catching expected text..
if I give /welcome/g as regex, it is showing "25 instances found"..
but if I give  regex, its not showing anything..

Comment: And? Did you get expected results? Are you sure you have regular spaces around `FIG`? Are there hard spaces?

Comment: the required text in pdf is as :
(REF 10-52-44 FIG 20 ...some text..)

from here it has to catch.. but it is not catching..
I need here only "10-52-44 FIG 20" to be caught...

Comment: there are regular spaces..
is there any method to hold hard spaces..
if you suggest me any other regex, then let me check it..

Comment: [Here is my post enumerating Unicode spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28618108/3832970). A regex to match them can be `/[\u0020\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200B\u202F\u205F\u3000\uFEFF]/g`. Please check again with `/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}[\s\u0020\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200B\u202F\u205F\u3000\uFEFF]+FIG[\s\u0020\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200B\u202F\u205F\u3000\uFEFF]+\d+/g`.

Comment: Use [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) to share your file conents that should be matched.

Answer (score 0):

In regex, the `[...]` square brackets is used to allow multiple options. For example, `[abc]` would be the same as writing `a|b|c`. Therefore, the brackets is changing the meaning of the expression within them. Remove the brackets.

```
var text = "test20-40-55 FIG 20test16-67-12 FIG 87";
text.match(/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} FIG [0-9]+/g);
```

Output:

```
["20-40-55 FIG 20", "16-67-12 FIG 87"]
```

Comment: I just checked by modifying the expression as below : 
/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} FIG [0-9]+/g

but also it is not matching a single instance...